# Symfony Form Using "_" In ID Field

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

For some reason, my generated pages are using for the field name article_id instead of articleid  as it is in my database and model.  I have tried running `"symfony doctrine:build --all"` and `"symfony doctrine:generate-module ..."` multiple times to no avail.

Here is an example of a bad generated file:

```
./apps/frontend/modules/article/templates/_form.php:            &nbsp;<?php echo link_to('Delete', 'article/delete?article_id='.$form->getObject()->getArticleId()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I tried cleaning as recommended, I also tried deleting the module and rebuilding it.

**EDIT 2**

After running "symfony doctrine:build --all" I do see this as a reference to the yml file used:

```
>> file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_97369.yml
```

Here is the Article section from the /tmp yml file:

```
Article:
  columns:
    ArticleID:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
      length: '4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that if you changed this name in your schema, that the old model files have kept the old name.  You can try to clean your model files using the task `doctrine:clean-model-files`

Comment: +1: I'd also check the schema file isn't being generated from a cached version instead of the latest one.

Comment: @Tom, tried what @Jon recommended to no avail.  How would I check to see what schema file is being used?

Comment: @Benny: when you do the "build --all" it says what schema file was used. A cached version might have a name like "schema_12323.yml" and be pulled from a temp folder somewhere instead of the project. You'd need to delete all cached versions and then re-build once more.

Comment: @Tom, please see my edit.  It looks like it's using a file like you said, but I even tried clearing the /tmp file of yml files, but a build after still yields the same results.

Comment: @Benny: Yep, seems that way. Delete all the similar schema files from the temp folder, run symfony cc, then re-build. All this does is that it ensures you're schema is being correctly generated from your current schema.yml. If this doesn't fix it, then it's not the cause of the original problem.